# PCRE - offset vector, multiple of 3?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I'm leraning PCRE and I don't understand why offset vector has to be multiple of 3. This is from pcredemo.c (`rc` is result from `pcre_exec()`):

```
/* The output vector wasn't big enough */

if (rc == 0) {
    rc = OVECCOUNT / 3;
    printf("ovector only has room for %d captured substrings\n", rc - 1);
}

/* Show substrings stored in the output vector by number. Obviously, in a real
 * application you might want to do things other than print them. */

for (i = 0; i < rc; i++) {
    char *substring_start = subject + ovector[2 * i];
    int substring_length = ovector[2 * i + 1] - ovector[2 * i];
    printf("%2d: %.*s\n", i, substring_length, substring_start);
}
```

To me it seems that ovector stores `str1_start, str1_end, str2_start, str2_end, ...`, so array could hold OVECCOUNT/2 strings. Why is it OVECCOUNT/3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcreapi):

> The first two-thirds of the vector is used to pass back captured
>   substrings, each substring using a pair of integers. **The remaining
>   third of the vector is used as workspace by pcre_exec() while matching
>   capturing subpatterns, and is not available for passing back
>   information.** The number passed in ovecsize should always be a multiple
>   of three. If it is not, it is rounded down.

Comment: I didn't get that far in manual yet. I better RTFM more next time. Thank you.